# Issue with Entity State, ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an error in the code below on EntityState, a google search proved this to be a fairly common error, the answer usually seems to be an incorrect 'using.' All the 'usings' seem to be in order here though.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.EntityState;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using WLL.Models;


  public void CategoryItems_DeleteItem(int categoryID)
    {
        var _db = new WLL.Models.ProductContext();

        {

            var item = new Category { CategoryID = categoryID };
            _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            try
            {
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

The error is as follows: Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Data.EntityState" to System.Data.Entity.EntityState" An explicit conversion exists."

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm using EF 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `_db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;` to `_db.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted` or remove `using System.Data;` if you do not need it in your code.

Comment: Thank you, that was just the ticket!